# A mecanim to optimize the number of requests, the use of the cache and the scripts load

Tags: javascript, html, http

The problem:

- it's better to make the less requests possible, because of the latency and the browser limitation about the number of simultaneaous requests.
- it's better to separate js libraries used to load only those needed, from the server or from the cache.
- this 2 rules are often not compatible.

So, I'd like to merge all the js files needed by a page, then split each file and place each on the cache. So, when I'll need a js file which has already been needed, it will be already in cache I'll load just this one.
This can be implement with the filesystem api, but the ideal were to reference files in cache by its original url on the server. I'd like to know if there was a mecanism to reference data by a url on the client.

Comment: The browser's built-in cache already does that.

Comment: That is impossible. The browser's cache mechanism only does cache whole files.

Comment: @Bergi: I don't want to let the browser split himself the merged file, I'd just like to be able to write a file on the client and reference it by a url on the domain of the website.

Comment: @Gael: You're looking for [File API object urls](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/31/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-4-object-urls/) ([W3 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url))? Might be possible, but I'm not sure whether that is a good strategy

Comment: In a sense, yes, but I'd like that the url has not the scheme filesystem://xxx but http://mydomain.com/js/myfile.js

Comment: No, impossible. That is (and must stay) a http connection to your server, not a local reference. If you want to manipulate the browser's cache that lot, you might want to have a look at manifest files

Comment: Thank you for the interest to my question. I was looking for a global solution, so manifest files and hosted apps do not fit. And things like SPDY will avoid the problem.